# Dual monitor extend (join) not working with Wayland with p14s ThinkPad laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, wayland

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad P14s gen4 amd laptop, which has an integrated GPU.

I installed Ubuntu 23.10, and it defaults to using Wayland and connected it to an external Dell Dell P2720D monitor via HDMI.

The UI under Settings > Displays then "Mirror", the default setting works, and I see the display duplicated as expected, with the large external monitor having a low resolution limited to that of the laptop.

But if I switch to "Join" does not allow to Apply with message:

> Changes Cannot be Applied. This could be due to hardware limitations.

Logging off and changing to X allows "Join" to work, so it is a Wayland issue.

Is there a way to make it work on Wayland? Mostly out of morbid curiosity.

Also dropping a bug at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xwayland/+bug/2048438